# C++ floating-point addition with bit shift error issues

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-shift

I am trying to calculate floating point addition with only using bit shifts and logical ands(&) and ors(|). I am aware that built in floating point addition is more practical, but this is needed for a class and I am lost. This code passes most cases my professor provided except 1000000000.5 + 0.008. The functions return 1.03436e+09, which is not correct.

```
#include <iostream>
// Function to reinterpret integer as float
float int_as_float(int value) {
    return *((float*)&value);
}

// Function to reinterpret float as integer
int float_as_int(float value) {
    return *((int*)&value);
}

// Function to add two floats without using floating-point instructions
float add_without_float(float a, float b) {
    // Check if one of the values is zero
    if (a == 0.0) {
        return b;
    }
    else if (b == 0.0) {
        return a;
    }

    // Reinterpret floats as integers for bit manipulation
    int aInt = float_as_int(a);
    int bInt = float_as_int(b);

    // Extracting sign, exponent, and mantissa components
    int signA = (aInt >> 31) & 1; // Extract sign bit of float 'a'
    int signB = (bInt >> 31) & 1; // Extract sign bit of float 'b'

    int expA = ((aInt >> 23) & 0xFF) - 127; // Extract exponent of float 'a' and adjust bias
    int expB = ((bInt >> 23) & 0xFF) - 127; // Extract exponent of float 'b' and adjust bias

    int mantissaA = ((aInt & 0x007FFFFF) | 0x00800000); // extracting the mantissa in the bottom 23 bits
    int mantissaB = ((bInt & 0x007FFFFF) | 0x00800000); // extracting the mantissa in the bottom 23 bits

    int shift = expA - expB;
    if (expA > expB) {
        mantissaB >>= shift; // Shift mantissa of 'b' to align exponents if 'expA > expB'
        expB = expA; // Update exponent of 'b'
    }
    else if (expA < expB) {
        mantissaA >>= -shift; // Shift mantissa of 'a' to align exponents if 'expA < expB'
        expA = expB; // Update exponent of 'a'
    }

    int resultSign;
    int resultMantissa;
    if (signA == signB) {
        resultMantissa = mantissaA + mantissaB;
        resultSign = signA;
    }
    else if (signA == 1) {
        resultMantissa = mantissaB - mantissaA;
        if (resultMantissa < 0) {
            resultSign = 1;
            resultMantissa = -resultMantissa;
        }
        else {
            resultSign = 0;
        }
        mantissaA = 0 - mantissaA; // twos compliment
    }
    else if (signB == 1) {
        resultMantissa = mantissaA - mantissaB;
        if (resultMantissa < 0) {
            resultSign = 1;
            resultMantissa = -resultMantissa;
        }
        else {
            resultSign = 0;
        }
    }

    //resultSign = (resultMantissa >> 31) & 0x1; // if result sign is 1, reverse it.. & 0x1 isolates one bit of 1
    unsigned resultExp = expA; // Adjust the biased exponent for the result
    int result;

    if (resultSign == 1) {
        resultMantissa = 0 - resultMantissa; // twos compliment
    }

    // Normalize the result mantissa in a fixed number of steps
    if (resultMantissa == 0) {
        result = 0;
        return result;
    }
    else if ((resultMantissa & 0x010000000) != 0) {  // 25th bit == 1
        resultMantissa = resultMantissa >> 1;
        resultExp++;
    }
    else {
        while ((resultMantissa & 0x00800000) == 0) { // 24th bit == 1

            resultMantissa = resultMantissa << 1;
            resultExp--;
        }
    }
    // Assemble the result by combining sign, exponent, and mantissa parts
    //std::cout << (resultSign << 31) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << ((resultExp + 127) << 23) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << (resultMantissa & 0x007FFFFF) << std::endl;

    result = (resultSign << 31) | ((resultExp + 127) << 23) | (resultMantissa & 0x007FFFFF);

    return int_as_float(result); // Reinterpret result as a float and return it
}

int main() {
    float a = 1000000000.5;
    float b = 0.008;

    // Perform addition without using floating-point instructions
    float result = add_without_float(a, b);

    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl; // Display the result

    return 0;
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You have to debug this. Do the calculations on paper. Then add print statements in code and check if the values match. Where it doesn't match, focus on that area.

Comment: "C" style casts like this may well lead to undefined behavior in C++ you have to use `memcpy` or `std::bitcast` (C++20). Also you should check that this equality `static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int));`  is true on your system

Comment: Also read [what is the modern correct way to do type punning in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636231/what-is-the-modern-correct-way-to-do-type-punning-in-c)

Comment: My compiler gives `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`.

Comment: The type punning is not the source of the issue (I checked that). But it is still worth fixing it. Try compiling with maximum warning level on too and fix ALL the warnings (there are a few)

Comment: `shift` is `36`, you can't shift a 32-bit `int` right by 36 bits

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394259/weird-behavior-of-right-shift-operator-1-32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the potential problems with [type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137442/what-is-type-punning-and-what-is-the-purpose-of-it), the problem is in the bit shifting of the mantissa. More precisely here:

```
   mantissaB >>= shift; // Shift mantissa of 'b' to align exponents if 'expA > expB'
```

In the test case, `shift` is 36 which apparently is larger than the bitsize of the `int` type causing [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918256/is-right-shift-undefined-behavior-if-the-count-is-larger-than-the-width-of-the-t). In your case, the result turns out to be simply wrong.

A fix could be to set `mantissaB` to `0` if `shift` is too big:

```
   mantissaB = (shift < 8*sizeof(int)) ? mantissaB >> shift : 0;
```

A similar fix must be made for `mantissaA`.

Note: If you include `#include <climits>`, then "8" can be replaced by the more correct `CHAR_BITS` which is not necessarily 8 (though it will be hard to find a system where it is not).

Comment: Whilst this will make the answer less wrong `1000000000.5` still isn't a great answer for `1000000000.5 + 0.008`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Given that `float` has 6-7 significant digits, it is as good as it gets.

Comment: Ah, yes `a` isn't even `1000000000.5` to start with, it's just `1000000000`

Comment: @nielsen: [`float` does not have 6-7 significant digits.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609276/how-to-calculate-float-type-precision-and-does-it-make-sense/61614323#61614323)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, the story is much longer (and thank you for linking to your excellent explanation), but the essence is that `0.008` is so small compared to `1000000000.5` that adding it to the best representable approximation of `1000000000.5` will not change the resulting value when using the `float` type. The minimal change that can be represented is tightly linked to the bit width of the significand in the floating-point representation. With the normal `float` that is 24 bits corresponding to about 7 decimal digits, so it is in that context my comment is meant (which was unclear).